# How JVM performs Serialization

Tags: serialization, jvm, classloader

We all know how serialization works and its mechanism,marker interface,deserialization etc. etc., but How does it happen inside or through jvm, more specifically which method reads the 'Serializable' and process the request ,if  there exists such a method?

Comment: “We all know how serialization works”— do we? How may Java developers did really read [the entire specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html)? If you did, you know what is specified and what is just an implementation detail that might change between different versions. If you want to know how a particular implementation works, look in its source code.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` performs serialization, `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` performs deserialization. The source code in available in JDK distribution inside `src.zip` - start looking from there.